# Indesign GREP: find everything before a matching sequence

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

Couldn't exactly find the answer in other threads. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

In the below example I want to apply a GREP style by finding only the title of the artwork. In this case, only the information before the comma on the first line.

```
My Beautiful Painting #3, 1999.
Oil on canvas
25 x 25cm
Gift of the artist.
```

I think this needs to be done via the "positive lookbehind" match function, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign! What have you tried? You're more likely to get a good answer if you show more effort

Comment: `^.*?(,|$)` works for everything up to (and, unfortunately, _including_ the comma). I only want it to run on the first line. This is why I want to use the lookbehind function – just struggling with getting results. So far this is what seemed to make sense to me `.(?=,\s\d{4})`

Comment: If your question is solved with that you could post it in more detail as an answer below to help others :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. Should have been using positive lookahead, not lookbehind. `.+(?=,\s\d{4})`. This article was helpful carijansen.com/2013/03/03/positive-lookahead-grep-for-designers